# Error: Unable to initialize main class App Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage

Tags: java, javafx

[image: Error code]

Yesterday I used vsc succesfully with my JAVA code, now I'm getting an error, but I didn't change anything
I'm getting this if I'm trying to run the code:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class App
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage

I tried:
Clean Java Language Server Workspace,
searched for it online (found nothing useful).

On my other pc it's working fine.

Comment: Follow the instructions for [JavaFX and Visual Studio Code](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode) at openjfx.io.

Comment: That error message does not include the path to `Stage`. Do you have an import `javafx.stage.Stage;` statement in your code?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I still got this JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Comment: The runtime components are missing error is not mentioned in your question.  There are [a hundred duplicate questions about missing JavaFX runtime components on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=“JavaFX+runtime+components”).   The primary answer is always the same, which is to follow the getting started instructions linked in my first comment.

Comment: Thank I got it, my bad. Thanks for your help, sorry for waste your time...